# How can I Git Push without triggering a build?

Tags: git

We currently have git setup so that whenever we push to the repository on our build server a bash script on the server is executed that starts a build.

Occasionally we make changes that **shouldn't** trigger a build.
Is there any extra parameter we could give to git push so that it doesn't execute the receive hooks, or passes the parameter into the receive hooks? Any other solutions to prevent a build being kicked off also welcome.

Comment: I would suggest a special keyword in the commit message, then parse the message in the hook.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the "special keyword in the commit message" suggested by [tauran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/405559/tauran) isn't a good solution enough, don't forget about **[`git notes`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-notes.html)**. (See [Notes to self](http://progit.org/2010/08/25/notes.html)).

You can attach any kind of text metadata to a commit (without having to change its SHA1).
You can then parse not for a commit message content, but for the existence of a special note on the pushed commits.

Comment: That's even better then the keyword :)